# docker-compose mounted volume remain

Tags: docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm using docker-compose in one of my projects. During development i mount my source directory to a volume in one of my docker services for easy development. At the same time, I have a db service (psql) that mounts a named volume for persistent data storage.

I start by solution and everything is working fine

```
$ docker-compose up -d
```

When I check my volumes I see the named and "unnamed" (source volume).

```
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               226ba7af9689c511cb5e6c06ceb36e6c26a75dd9d619360882a1012cdcd25b72
local               myproject_data
```

The problem I experience is that, when I do

```
$ docker-compose down
...
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               226ba7af9689c511cb5e6c06ceb36e6c26a75dd9d619360882a1012cdcd25b72
local               myproject_data
```

both volumes remain. Every time I run

```
$ docker-compose down
$ docker-compose up -d
```

a new volume is created for my source mount

```
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               19181286b19c0c3f5b67d7d1f0e3f237c83317816acbdf4223328fdf46046518
local               226ba7af9689c511cb5e6c06ceb36e6c26a75dd9d619360882a1012cdcd25b72
local               myproject_data
```

I know that this will not happen on my deployment server, since it will not mount the source, but is there a way to not make the mounted source persistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `--rm` option in docker run. To use it with [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/rm/) you can use

`docker-compose rm -v` after stopping your containers with  `docker-compose stop`

If you go through the docs about [Data volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) , its mentioned that

> Data volumes persist even if the container itself is deleted.

So that means, stopping a container will not remove the volumes it created, whether named or anonymous.

Now if you read further down to `Removing volumes`

> A Docker data volume persists after a container is deleted. You can
>   create named or anonymous volumes. Named volumes have a specific
>   source form outside the container, for example awesome:/bar. Anonymous
>   volumes have no specific source. When the container is deleted, you
>   should instruct the Docker Engine daemon to clean up anonymous
>   volumes. To do this, use the --rm option, for example:
>
> ```
> $ docker run --rm -v /foo -v awesome:/bar busybox top
> ```
>
> This command creates an anonymous /foo volume. When the container is
>   removed, the Docker Engine removes the /foo volume but not the awesome
>   volume.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This somewhat worked, but if I call `docker-compose rm -v` after `docker-compose down`, I get `No stopped containers`. I have to fall `docker-compose stop` followed by `docker-compose rm -v` to remove my anonymous volumes.

To the best of my understanding, this is the best approach. However, It would be nice with a flag for this in `docker-compose down`. Similar to the `--volumes` flag for named volumes.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove volumes with the down command:

```
docker-compose down -v
```